# Where does R store its packages?

Tags: r

After installing a certain package, the package is not loadable via `library("stm")`. It says it doesn't exist. I think the intallation directory is not the same as when using the `library` function. Anyone knows how to fix this?

thanks in advance

Comment: Since this is 100% unrelated to GCP, I’ve removed that part.

Answer (score 1):

You can view (and edit) the location of your libraries with `.libPaths()`.
Here is the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/libPaths).

If you use `library()`, it will output all packages installed in your current library path.

Comment: Adding to this, you can ask R to always use a custom library by having `.libPaths( "/user/Ryp/your-library" )` in your .RProfile.